# How present only two buttons on a tablet screen

Tags: buttons, tablet

My application has need of only two button with around 15 characters for each, on the main screen. The problem is the screen is large on tablet. How can I present these two button ?

Comment: You could make the 2 buttons really big or not so big but adding some descriptions to them. But it's an opinion-based question. :\

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Centered design, on top of each other both in landscape and portrait? Looks easy to use, but it really depends on context. I'm assuming the buttons are a group, and that's the basis of my design

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f33OSc.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Is only for a landscape display, thanks for your response